# How to retrieve external data while offline in mobile safari

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

I'm building several apps using the HTML5 standard with the intention of running them offline in Mobile Safari.  Most of these apps provide a graphical representation of data collected in several massive plain text files that are going to be packaged alongside the core app files.  I need a way to retrieve the data in these files and represent them as a String or some other readable object in Javascript.

From my limited amount of research it would appear that cross-origin restrictions prevent me from doing this, even though all files are working from a local directory.  Is there something I'm missing or is there no way for me to accomplish what I'm after?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use JSON. You can grab data cross-domain using [JSON-P](http://json-p.org/) if needed. JSON is also local-storage friendly.

Comment: After a bit of a struggle I got this to work.  However, this brought up another issue that seems to be inherent in the way js processes strings.  As far as I know, strings may only be created on the same line.  I can't say: 
var myString = "text
                on
                several
                lines";
Because of this, I would have to go into the original .txt data files and paste the thousands of lines of data into their own JSON string representation in my new file, rather than copying the entire text and pasting it into a single JSON string element (as I originally tried to do).

Comment: Apparently you can't include new lines in comments. [var myString = "text on several lines"] should read as [var myString = "text\n on \n several \n lines"].